# Has anybody used "Flexpex"

Tags: plumbing, pex

I am fixing a leak in my RV plumbing a ran into a new plumbing system called Flex Pex or possibly FlexPex, which is clear pex-like tubing and plastic compression fittings. I  could deal with Pex, but this tubing doesn't pop loose from the fittings using reasonable force. I also don't know where to source the replacement T-joint I need.
AKG

Comment: I like to wait a few years before trying new systems.  Wait for the bugs/lawsuits to come or not.  Plumbing stores should have or know where to source.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm answering my own question. The fittings are called "Flair-it fittings" and are available on Amazon.com, at least. Removing them just takes patience and some hand strength wiggling the fitting loose from the pipe. Eventually they pop off. Whether I could have replaced the RV FlexPex tubing with regular Pex is an unknown; I won't try it unless I have no other option.